# PNPPowershell code does not remove the first 5 rows of a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have this code to remove the last 5 rows of a Sharepoint list and it works fine.
But when i change -Last to -First it does not remove the first 5 rows. What is wrong with the code?

```
$SiteURL = "xxxxxxx"
$ListName = "xxxxxx"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000

#Get the last 20 row items
$Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName | select -Last 6
ForEach ($Item in $Items)
{
   $ItemID = $Item["ID"]   
   $ItemID
   #Remove the item and saves it in the Recycle Bin
   Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $ItemID -Force -Recycle
   Write-Host "Delete the Item Title : " $Item["Title"] 
}
```

Gr P.

Comment: How many items do you have in the list? You use pagesize on row 4 so I assume it's over the threshold, but then you get the listitems again at row 7 but without pagesize so I think you are getting the latest 5000 items and are deleting the first 5 of those.

Comment: (Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName ).ItemCount to check the item count. If it's above 5000, you need to use PageSize so the items get's querried in batches, and then selecting -first 5 should return the right result.

Comment: I have 586 items I wish to delete the first 6 rows for just for testing.

Comment: Do you use any custom sort through views or such? Or is it ID 1-5 that should be deleted? Your code worked fine for me. Check that the variable $Items holds after running row 7.

Comment: My list is sorted Descended. My first column is a date column and i wish the newest row on top of my list. I want to delete the last 6 rows but because its sorted Descended i have to put -First instead of -Last

Comment: Ah, but Get-PnPListItem will always return the order of the ID and ignore any sort-orders made in SharePoint manually or through views, so you have to apply the same sorting when retrieving the items.

$Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName | Sort-Object DateColumn -Descending | Select-Object -First 5

Comment: It works thank you, How can i close this question